# Crashes when getting bitmap

Tags: java, android, eclipse

If I comment out the line decoding the `bitmap` and (`xpos` and `ypos` since they use it) It doesn't crash. However if they are `uncommented` it crashes. I don't know why.

```
public class ClSprite implements Parcelable{

    private Bitmap SpriteBitmap;    // the actual bitmap
    private boolean Touched;    // if droid is touched/picked up
    private int XVelocity;
    private int YVelocity;
    private int XPosition; 
    private int YPosition;
    private boolean Visible;
    private String SpriteType;
    private int BitmapLocation;


    public ClSprite(int givenBitmapLocation, int xPosition, int yPosition, int VelocityX, int VelocityY, String spriteType)
    {
        //Needs this constructor filled in.
        BitmapLocation = givenBitmapLocation;
        SpriteBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Game.context.getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
        XPosition = xPosition - SpriteBitmap.getWidth()/2;
        YPosition = yPosition - SpriteBitmap.getHeight()/2;
        XVelocity = VelocityX;
        YVelocity = VelocityY;
        Visible = true;
        SpriteType = spriteType;
    }
```

Comment: 'Game' is the main activity where context is a static and assigned in the oncreate as context = this;

Comment: here is the log file in txt b/c its too big to fit in comment section. http://www.mediafire.com/?7mh4733ik5rr9dx

Comment: Are you getting outofmemory error.

Comment: 08-08 06:32:15.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.GuessingLetters/com.GuessingLetters.Game}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.GuessingLetters.GameView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your LogCat shows an OutOfMemoryError. Something like this: "OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget".

If this is true you need to fix or dynamically scale your bitmap. Please have a look here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488

Comment: not that i could see in the log. can you think of something else

Comment: Your code in the OP shows a custom class. I thought you posted this code because these are the lines from your error. Your LogCat says something different. I have to remove my bet. Your error log shows an Inflate error and points to an exact XML file/line. Did you check that XML file at line 21? And what about your onCreate() in the Activity where this error pops up?

Comment: this is line 21 which shouldn't matter to the constructor of the ClSprite   <com.GuessingLetters.GameView
      android:id="@+id/lunar"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

Comment: So the error is within com.GuessingLetters.GameView. What does this class extend and what does the constructor of this class do?

Comment: this is what calls that line in the xml file. mLunarView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.lunar);

Comment: class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Comment: public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        MaskVisible = true;
        thread = new GameThread(holder, context, new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
                mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
                mStatusText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        });
        setFocusable(true);
    }